# Update large table from smaller, mission critical, table without locking small table

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

In MySQL, I have two innodb tables, a small mission critical table, that needs to be readily available at all times for reads/writes. Call this mission_critical. I have a larger table (>10s of millions of rows), called big_table. I need to update big_table, for instance:

```
update mission_critical c, big_table b
set
b.something = c.something_else
where b.refID=c.id
```

This query could take more than an hour, but this creates a write-lock on the mission_critical table. Is there a way I can tell mysql, "I don't want a lock on mission_critical" so that that table can be written to?

I understand that this is not ideal from a transactional point of view. The only workaround I can think of right now is to make a copy of the small mission_critical table and do the update from that (which I don't care gets locked), but I'd rather not do that if there's a way to make MySQL natively deal with this more gracefully.

It is not the table that is locking but all of the records in mission_critical that are locked, since they are basically all scanned by the update. I am not assuming this; the symptom is that when a user logs in to an online system, it tries to update a datetime column in mission_critical to update the last time they logged in. These queries die due to a Lock wait timeout exceeded error while the query above is running. If I kill the query above, all pending queries run immediately.

mission_critical.id and big_table.refID are both indexed.

The pertinent portions of the creation statements for each table is:

mission_critical:

```
CREATE TABLE `mission_critical` (
`intID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`something_else` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`lastLoginDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`intID`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `something_else` (`something_else`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1432 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

big_table:

```
CREATE TABLE `big_table` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`postDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`postTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`refID` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`something` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`change` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `refID` (`refID`),
KEY `postDate` (`postDate`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=138139125 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The explanation of the query is:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type |      table       | partitions | type | possible_keys |  key  | key_len |                ref                 | rows | filtered |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mission_critical |            | ALL  | id            |       |         |                                    |  774 |      100 | Using where |
|  1 | UPDATE      | big_table        |            | ref  | refID         | refID |       3 | db.mission_critical.something_else | 7475 |      100 |             |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: InnoDB does not table lock, InnoDB locks records and it might be locking a foreiyn key , Also you should not be using the old comma ansi join annymore.. And if your MySQL version supports it use `EXPLAIN update...` Also provide table structure off both tables `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`

Comment: How big is the "small" table?

Comment: @Paul, the small table is about 1000 rows.

Comment: Do you have an index on `b.refID`? And did you run a test which tells you that the table is locked for updates, or are you making assumptions?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've added the extra details in the edited version of the question.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Take a look at the edits in the question. That column is indexed. And other queries are dying to to lock wait timeouts. The table is currently something like 140M rows, so I expect it to take a while to update. It's really a question of the locking of mission_critical.

Comment: Post a explain.. `EXPLAIN <query>`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Just added the explanation of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first suggested a workaround with a subquery, to create a copy in an internal temporary table. But in my test the small table was still locked for writes. So I guess your best bet is to make a copy manually.

The reason for the lock is described in this bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72005

This is what *Sinisa Milivojevic* wrote in an answer:

> `update table t1,t2 ....`
>
> any `UPDATE` with a join is considered a multiple-table update. In that
>   case, a referenced table has to be read-locked, because rows must not
>   be changed in the referenced table during `UPDATE`  until it has
>   finished. There can not be concurrent changes of the rows, nor `DELETE`
>   of the rows, nor, much less, exempli gratia any DDL on the referenced
>   table. The goal is simple, which is to have all tables with consistent
>   contents when `UPDATE` finishes, particularly since multiple-table
>   `UPDATE` can be executed with several passes.

In short, this behavior is for a good reason.

Consider writing INSERT and UPDATE triggers, which will update the `big_table` on the fly. That would delay writes on the `mission_critical` table. But it might be fast enough for you, and wouldn't need the mass-update-query any more.

Also check if it wouldn't be better to use `char(50)` instead of `varchar(50)`. I'm not sure, but it's possible that it will improve the update performance because the row size wouldn't need to change. I could improve the update performance about 50% in a test.

Comment: @RaymondNijland See OP's comment: "the small table is about 1000 rows".

Comment: oh never mind i readed the question wrong, i was thinking the mission_critical was 10> millions off records.. You never saw and read mine comment

Comment: *"My "hope" is that the subquery will create an internal temporary table, and so the engine wouldn't need to lock the rows in the original table."* talking about temporary table why not make you own temporary table (`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`) with indexes and use that temporary table as update id's

Comment: @RaymondNijland Making a table copy is the first what I thought, and also a considered workaround of OP. And it might be the only way, since the lock is there for a good reason, even with the subquery. Which makes my answer invalid.

Comment: yes i think the topicstarter will be ok when making a own temporary table outside a transaction and filling the temporary table and doing the update in a transaction as this should not lock the records in the table `mission_critical` that long..

Comment: ... still hoping MySQL would support (native) [materialized views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) soon that would also open new approaches to handle cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE will lock the rows that it needs to change. It may also lock the "gaps" after those rows.

You may use MySQL transactions in loop
Update only 100 rows at once

BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;  -- arrange to have this select include the 100 rows
UPDATE ...;  -- update the 100 rows
COMMIT;

Answer (score 0):

May be worth trying a correlated subquery to see if the optimiser comes up with a different plan, but performance may be worse.

```
update big_table b
set b.something = (select c.something_else from mission_critical c where b.refID = c.id)
```